# How do I add values to an existing column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas columns as such:

```
    Free-Throw Percentage
0   .371
1   .418
2   .389
3   .355
4   .386
5   .605
```

And I have a list of values: [.45,.31,.543]

I would like to append these values to the above column such that the final result would be:

```
Free-Throw Percentage
0 .371
1 .418
2 .389
3 .355
4 .386
5 .605
6 .45
7 .31
8 .543
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your "list" of values a plain Python list, or is it a Series or NumPy array?

Answer (score -1):

```
df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Free-Throw Percentage':[.45,.31,.543]}))
```

should do the job

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(np.random.randint(0, 20, 10), np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)), columns=['A', 'B'])

new_vals = [3, 4, 5]

df_1 = df_1.append(pd.DataFrame({'B': new_vals}), sort=False, ignore_index=True)

print(df_1)
```

Comment: @dexter pardon?

Comment: @dexter Well now I can't even look at your answer to see if I had made a mistake...

Comment: @dexter I didn't have time to mention the `ignore_index` parameter, which I consider to be quite useful, especially since the index here is quite simple _and_ OP's post shows the "correct"/reset index.